# Do the iMac and Mac Pro have the same need to be physically cleaned as a normal PC?

Tags: mac, cleaning

Do the iMac or Mac Pro need to be cleaned physically for maintenance like a normal PC?

Since all computers get dirty with time, and need to be cleaned for maintence and good performance, I was wondering if the Mac Pro and iMac also need such cleaning.

Comment: Should be on SuperUser. (or ServerFault)

Comment: Nah, the patented Steve Jobs "reality displacement field" keeps all the dirt away.

Comment: I was unaware that regular computers ever needed to be cleaned. :-)

Comment: You should check this out and decide for yourself...http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/11/13/ventblockers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I periodically open up my Mac pro and vacuum out the dust that the case fans tend to accumulate. The iMac's harder to access, but it's less prone to dust too. Other than said dust control, you shouldn't need to clean anything.

Answer (score 1):

They’re no more or less dirt-prone that other computers.

> all computers... need to be cleaned for maintence and good performance

I’d query the good performance part. Sounds like nonsense.

Comment: If components run too hot they'll often downclock themselves in order to stay within temperature limits. It's not that far-fetched :P

Comment: Or shut down entirely...

Comment: Sure — overheating will diminish performance, dust in the wrong place will cause overheating, cleaning the dust out will stop the overheating. I’ve just got an irrational dislike of vague advice.